# Deletion Error with Email Validation in Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation, email

So I've recently taken over an Angular Giving Form Application. I am running validation on the email field using ng-pattern and displaying the errors on blur with ngMessages. The validation works great, however once the validation passes as $valid if the user decides they need to make a change in their email and begin to delete part of the first deletion deletes the last character of the email as expected, but the second deletion deletes the entire field forcing the user to start from scratch.

The regex for ng-pattern is being set in the controller scope with the variable $scope.emailre

The files are much to large to place here but here is the link to the site I am working on for my client.
https://epiqa.moodyglobal.org/corporate/

Snippet of Angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService, $http) {
$scope.emailre = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Snippet of HTML Form:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>
            <label class="label" for="txt_donorEmail">E-mail:</label>
            <input  ng-class="{ 'submitted-error' : givingForm.email.$invalid && submitted }" ng-model="email" type="text" id="email" name="email" class="textbox required full form-control" maxlength="50" ng-pattern="emailre" required />
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="givingForm.email.$error" ng-if="givingForm.email.$touched || submitted">
            <div class="errorText" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            <div class="errorText" ng-message="pattern">Enter a valid email</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the input type from type="text" to type="email" but when doing that any time the user types two (.) periods the field gets immediately deleted.

Please help any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is caused by this section

```
$scope.$watch('email', function(value){
  localStorageService.set('email',value);
  $scope.emailValue = localStorageService.get('email');
});
```

By Angular documentation

> The default behaviour in `ngModel` is that the model value is set to `undefined` when the validation determines that the value is invalid. By setting the `allowInvalid` property to true, the model will still be updated even if the value is invalid.

I'm not sure whether you want to save the invalid email into `localStorage`, though. Maybe you can add a check only update when the value is valid.